# icon font in a box not displaying correctly in IE

Tags: css, wordpress, icons

I use Wordpress with the UDesign theme which includes iconfonts and I use these on my website to show icons in small blue boxes, you can see them on this page.

http://www.whichgreekisland.co.uk/islands/corfu/beaches/agnos/

I had to customise the CSS to get it to display in the boxes, I found a tutorial online that did it with circles and I simply changed the border radius to make them squares with rounded corners. so it uses a class called .circle-icon which has the following css on it.

```
color: #FFF;
font-size: 2.4em;
background: #018ED7 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 6px;
line-height: 2.6em;
margin-right: 10px;
border-radius: 3px;
```

They display correctly on Chrome and Firefox, as in, the icon is in the centre of the box but in IE the bottom of the box is missing so the icon is at the bottom of the box and the box is too small.

I've tried changing the css but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong or is there a better way of getting these icons in the center of a small blue box with rounded corners?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the `<i>` tag is wrong. In HTML, `<i>` should stand for alternate parts of text (usually render in italic) and so is an inline element. Sometimes it is used to render an icon, but it is a semantic missuse.

So if you use `<i>` to render an icon you should change his display mode to `inline-block`. Actually the size of your icon is just calculated from the size of the pseudo element `:before`, the `line-height` and the padding (which can render oddly on inline elements). So your width and height properties of 120px are not applied.

What you need to do is to add the following rules to get the same render as it currently is in Chrome/FF, but in `inline-block`:

```
i {
  display: inline-block
  width: 53px;
  height: 48px;
}
i:before {
  line-height: 48px; /* vertically center the icon */
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, it's stretched the social icons on the left of the page in IE but nothings changed on these icons.

Comment: I still see the old properties, the icons are still inline. Just try to change the display mode through your browser debugger and see.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I've changed the css to be this and now it works. Appreciate your help.

    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 48px;
    background: #018ed7; 
    width: 500x;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 14px 8px 3px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;